# what are the steps to solve the following equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have following differential equation $$xd\left(\frac{dg(x)}{dx}\right)=df\left(\frac{dg(x)}{dx}\right)\tag 1$$ which I obtained from the equation $$x=f'(g'(x)).$$ Actually I want to find $f(g'(x)). $ So how to further solve equation (1) above to get $f(g'(x))$?

Comment: What does $f'$ exactly mean ?

Comment: @LostInSpace $f'(g'(x))=\frac{df\left(g'(x)\right)}{dg'(x)}$ and $g'(x)=\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$.

Comment: Then your notation is really bad you can't have prime that has different meaning for f and g

Comment: @LostInSpace how to solve it then?

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

$$
d(u(x)) = u'(x) dx\\
z = \frac{dg(x)}{dx}\\
LHS\\
d\left(z\right) = \frac{dz}{dx} dx\\
xd\left(z\right) = x\frac{dz}{dx} dx\\
RHS\\
d\left(f(z)\right) = f'(z)\frac{dz}{dx}  dx\\
x\frac{dz}{dx} dx = f'(z)\frac{dz}{dx}  dx\\
$$

Comment: I think not useful. I need to perform integration on both sides of equation (1). Can you help with that integration?